# Thymeleaf dynamic data validation

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

in my case I'm receiving HTML thymeleaf from the client and when its requested, I fetch this HTML template from the db. and with the request I will have the data to fill in the thymeleaf variables.
the question here is how can I indicate that some variables are required from the HTML thymeleaf, my templates are so dynamic and its hard to create objects for them. I'm open to any solution even replacing the thymeleaf with something else.

example:

```
<div style="color:#3a3a3a;font-size:18px;font-weight:400;">
     <strong>ORDER ID:</strong> [[${bookingId}]] |
     <strong>BILLING DATE:</strong> [[${billingDate}]]
</div>
```

how can I put in this html that the bookingId is required(I have a map that has the values I need to fill).

any way to validate this against the data I have.
thanks in advance

Comment: What if you add a required attribute on the html tag. Eg <strong required="required">ORDER ID:</strong>

Comment: I need the validation on the thymeleaf expression ${bookingId} not on the html itself

Comment: You could wrap the bookingId with a html tag and pass the required attributes, then you can validate the value inside. <span required="required">[[${bookingId}]]</span>